# OnResume from specific activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

Im integrating TapResearch in my Android app. As mentioned here in the documentation https://www.tapresearch.com/docs/android-integration-guide that the to show the survey I need to use `TapResearch.getInstance().showSurvey();`. This method open an activity from the library.

In the documentation there is a listener `onSurveyModalClosed()` so I can put anything once the activity is finished, but this listener does not work.

Since `onSurveyModalClosed()` does not function. In the MainActivity I want the app to do something OnResume from TapResearch Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

If the resume happens upon returning from TapResearch Activity {
Do something.
}
}
```

I think this is the activity path import

```
com.tapr.internal.activities.survey.SurveyActivity;
```

Comment: can you update the question with code for setting the listener, calling the showSurvey() and initialization of library?

Answer (score 0):

**This may not be the best answer available but a workaround as this is the only thing I found for myself.**

Whenever a specific activity is launched, I set a boolean variable as True in `OnCreate()` of that launched activity using [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) (sample code below), and when returning back to MainAcitivity, I check whether the variable is true and if true, then a specific code is executed.

In `OnCreate()` of launched activity:

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);        
tinydb.putBoolean("isMyActivity",true);
```

And in `OnResume()` of MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(tinydb.getBoolean("isMyActivity")) {
        yourMethod();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store the boolean or a `public static boolean` variable. I use TinyDB for many things. This works great.